# Galera, preciso criar um código em shell script pra descobrir o MTU da rede local com um laço

Tags: bash, shell-script

vou mandar a tarefa.
Objetivo: identificar o valor do MTU utilizado na rede TCP/IP
local, de forma dinâmica e com alguma heurística para, desta forma,
minimizar a quantidade de iterações na determinação desse valor

Busca binária só faz sentido em vetores ordenados. Um vetor v[0..n-1] está
em ordem crescente se:
v[0] <= v[1] <=  ...  <=  v[n - 1].

Algoritmo:

```
 #define NAOEXISTE -1
 // Recebe um numero x e um vetor crescente
 // v[e..d] com n >= 0. Devolve j tal que v[j] == x
 // ou devolve NAOEXISTE se tal j não existe.

 int bb(int x, int v[], int e, int d) {
    if (e > d) return NAOEXISTE;
    else {
       int m;
       m = (e + d)/2;
       if (v[m] == x) return m;
       if (v[m] < x) return bb(x, v, m+1, d);
       else return bb(x, v, e, m-1);
    }
 }
```

A atividade consiste em elaborar um algoritmo que faça uso da
referida heurística, para minimizar a quantidade de iterações necessárias
na determinação do MTU.
. A ideia é utilizar um laço de repetição para executar o comando ping
com diferentes quantidades de dados (incrementando ou decrementando essa
quantidade) e sempre com a opção de não fragmentação ativa, de forma a
induzir um erro de envio. A identificação do erro, que indica a necessidade
de fragmentação, pode ser utilizada para determinar o valor do MTU para
a tecnologia de enlace da sua rede.

Agora o código que estou fazendo no que puderem ajudar agradeço...tem tempo que to nessa luta

```
echo "Laboratório de Redes de Computadores"
echo "------------------------------------"
echo "Nome completo: Marcelo"
echo "------------------------------------"

aux1=`ifconfig | grep "inet " | awk '{print $3'\t'$4'\t'$5'\t'$6}'`
echo "${aux1}" 

echo "Determinacao do valor do MTU "
echo
i=0
for i in {1471..1473}; do
    echo "ping com 1 pacote Nao Fragmentado com a QUANTIDADEdeDADOS:${i} 192.168.0.1"
    echo
    AUX=`ping -c 1 -s ${i} -M do 192.168.0.1 | grep "local error" | awk '{print}'`
    echo "${AUX}" #Esse aux não printa na tela não sei pq
#   if [ -f $AUX ] #daí não consigo fazer esse if
#   then
    echo
    echo "maximo de bytes por pacote na rede: ${i}"
#   sleep 4s
#   exit
#   fi
done
```

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi bem a ideia do exercício, se o script deve ter tratamento de erros ou não, mas eu dei uma melhorada no que vc fez. Veja se ajuda.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Laboratório de Redes de Computadores"
echo "------------------------------------"
echo "Nome completo: Marcelo"
echo "------------------------------------"

aux1=`ifconfig | grep "inet " | awk '{print $3'\t'$4'\t'$5'\t'$6}'`
echo "${aux1}" 

echo "Determinacao do valor do MTU "
echo
i=0

for i in {1471..1473}
  do
    echo "ping com 1 pacote Nao Fragmentado com a QUANTIDADEdeDADOS:${i} 192.168.0.1"
    echo
    echo "ping -c 1 -s ${i} -M do 192.168.0.1"
    
    ping -c 1 -s ${i} -M do 192.168.0.1 | grep "local error" | awk '{print}'
    echo "maximo de bytes por pacote na rede: ${i}"
#   if [ -f $AUX ] #daí não consigo fazer esse if
#   then
#   sleep 4s
#   exit
#   fi
  done
```